# Buffer entire file in memory with Node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer

I have a relatively small file (some hundreds of kilobytes) that I want to be in memory for direct access for the entire execution of the code.

I don't know exactly the internals of Node.js, so I'm asking if a `fs open` is enough or I have to read all file and copy to a `Buffer`?

Comment: Look at the [readFile()](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback), this is what you need.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Basically, you need to use the `readFile` or `readFileSync` function from the `fs` module. They return the complete content of the given file, but differ in their behavior (asynchronous versus synchronous).

If blocking Node.js (e.g. on startup of your application) is not an issue, you can go with the synchronized version, which is as easy as:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = fs.readFileSync('/etc/passwd');
```

If you need to go asynchronous, the code is like that:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data ) {
  // ...
});
```

Please note that in either case you can give an `options` object as the second parameter, e.g. to specify the encoding to use. If you omit the encoding, the raw buffer is returned:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err, data ) {
  // ...
});
```

Valid encodings are `utf8`, `ascii`, `utf16le`, `ucs2`, `base64` and `hex`. There is also a `binary` encoding, but it is deprecated and should not be used any longer. You can find more details on how to deal with encodings and buffers in the appropriate [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Comment: small typo, missing comma after encoding in readFile function (I cant correct because the edit is less than 6 chars)

Answer (score 26):

As easy as

```
var buffer = fs.readFileSync(filename);
```

Answer (score 17):

With Node 0.12, it's possible to do this synchronously now:

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');

  // Buffer mydata
  var BUFFER = bufferFile('../public/mydata');

  function bufferFile(relPath) {
    return fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, relPath)); // zzzz....
  }
```

`fs` is the file system.  [readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) returns a Buffer, or string if you ask.

`fs` correctly assumes relative paths are a security issue.  `path` is a work-around.

To load as a string, specify the encoding:

```
return readFileSync(path,{ encoding: 'utf8' });
```