# Image data not saving to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

*Preface: using Node.js w/Express to build a blog website and using multer to upload an image to mongoDB.*

I have a problem with image data not saving to MongoDB.

When I use enctype="multipart/form-data in my HTML form, I get the following in my terminal

```
fieldname: 'myImage',
  originalname: 'photo_2021-12-27_20-07-58.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: './uploads/',
  filename: 'photo_2021-12-27_20-07-58.jpg',
  path: 'uploads\\photo_2021-12-27_20-07-58.jpg',
  size: 134172
}
```

Which is correct, the image also uploads into a separate uploads folder which is also correct, however the image data doesn't save to my mongoDB.

However, when I remove enctype="multipart/form-data", I don't have the file data in my terminal, nor does the image upload to the separate folder. However I DO! get the image data in my mongoDB. This is such a weird problem. Can anyone help?

Also, sorry for the amount of code I have just unleashed. If anyone actually takes the time to answer this then thank you!

**Routes**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const blogController = require('../controllers/blogController')
const multer = require('multer');


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  //destination for files
  destination: function (request, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads/');
  },

  //add back the extension
  filename: function (request, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  },
});


const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
});

router.get('/create', blogController.blog_create_get);

router.get('/', blogController.blog_home);

router.post('/', upload.single('myImage') ,blogController.blog_create_post);

router.get('/:id', blogController.blog_details);

router.delete('/:id', blogController.blog_delete_post);

module.exports = router
```

**Controller code**

```
const blog_create_post = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  const blog = new Blog(req.body, {

  })

  blog.save()
    .then(() => {
      res.redirect('/blogs')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}
```

**Schema**

```
  image: {

    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String
   
  },


const Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema)
module.exports = Blog;
```

**Midleware**

```
// Static Files | Middleware
app.use(express.static('Public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use('/uploads',express.static('uploads'))
```

**HTML form**

```
    <form action="/blogs" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <label for="image">Select image:</label>
      <input type="file" id="image" name="myImage" accept="image/*">
      <input type="submit" value = "Upload Photo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Multer is triggered only when the `enctype` of your form is `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Example from their [doc](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage):

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

When you don't provide this `enctype` your `req` object contains form data in text, and then it is saved to your database, of course.

In order to save binary data to MongoDB you need to open a file designated by

```
filename: 'photo_2021-12-27_20-07-58.jpg',
path: 'uploads\\photo_2021-12-27_20-07-58.jpg',
```

and save it appropriately (as text or binary depending on the format and reqs) to the mongodb. To read file check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706673/1333262)